# Property does not have a property named 'MAPID'

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2012

I am working on building an HTML 5 web-app in VS2012 and received this error in the display of my page from the MasterPage.

[image]

If someone could advise me what this actually means?  I have looked at the documentation and there is no MAPID property.  Also have this same error for the ScriptManager for all the JavaScript files.

Code In question:

```
            <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a id="registerLink" runat="server" href="~/Account/Register.aspx">Register</a></li>
                        <li><a id="loginLink" runat="server" href="~/Account/Login.aspx">Log in</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    <p>
                        Hello, <a runat="server" class="username" href="~/Account/Manage.aspx" title="Manage your account">
                            <asp:LoginName runat="server" CssClass="username" /></a>!
                        <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" />
                    </p>
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: Rebuild your Web application and re-start visual studio.

Comment: done it twice now, once yesterday and just now

Comment: Search in your project where you did use `'MAPID''.

Comment: Didnt, it was a fresh project.  Its an HTML 5 Asp.Net Web-App.